# Error Null Pointer Exception on XML Layout File Android

Tags: android, xml, classnotfoundexception

i have a problem regarding the android XML file. I created a layout called profile_page.xml and reference the layout for the table's borders from another file called profile_table_layout.xml; Below is code for profile_page.xml file ....

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <include
    android:id="@+id/header_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/header_master" />
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    >
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/table_userDesc" 
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:background="@drawable/profile_table_layout" >
                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableUserDesc" 
                          android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="TextView"></TextView>
                    <TextView android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="TextView"></TextView>
                    <TextView  android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="TextView"></TextView>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" 
                          android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content">                    

                    <TextView android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="TextView"></TextView>
                    <TextView android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="TextView"></TextView>
                    <TextView android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="TextView"></TextView>

                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I just having error code:

```
  error!
   NotFoundException: null
   Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
   The following classes could not be found:
   - TextView
```

How to resolve this? thanks.

Comment: hi @sachy, i couldn't running the application, it shows dialog that you cannor run the app because you have errors. thanks

Comment: hi @randytan: in your xml your are using textView1 id multiple times. Ids should be unique.
Secondly what you have written is error log output. Please add the LogCat output from Window > Show View > Logcat.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without knowing what your application code is doing, but from that error it looks like you might need to import android.widget.TextView into your .java file.

Comment: hi there jeremy, i can't fix this error. I have imported android.widget.TextView and nothing was changed.

Comment: In that case, to provide more help I would need to see more of your code than just this XML file.